# Why is the MySQL notation "UNIQUE field (field)" causing an error in MySQL 5.7.21?

Tags: mysql

I ran into a new problem today, when I was dealing with a [mysql query](https://github.com/q2a/question2answer/issues/595) that works on 10.1.19-MariaDB localhost, but not on MySQL 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log:

```
CREATE TABLE testing (
   pageid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   position SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (pageid), 
   UNIQUE position (position)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8
```

In MySQL 5.6 it works without any hickups ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/483d3e/2)), however, in MySQL 5.7.21 ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5vng5nVB6Ht4vNDiGqZQNs/0)) it throws:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'position (position)) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8' at line 1

I figured out a solution by replacing `UNIQUE position (position)` with `UNIQUE (position)`.

But I am wondering, what the underlying problem is, why it works with the other db system, and I am not sure if my solution is correct.

Comment: When i select MySQL 5.6 with your second Fiddle, it throws the error but not with the first fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why it is so important to wrap field and table names in backticks in MySQL (and their derivatives):

Try this (same query and index names, only added backticks):

```
CREATE TABLE `testing` (
   `pageid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `position` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`pageid`),
   UNIQUE `position` (`position`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Wow, that works. Thanks. Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5vng5nVB6Ht4vNDiGqZQNs/2 - Mini disclaimer: The code was not from me ;)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't allow you to create an index with the same name of the column

The following code works for MySQL ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5vng5nVB6Ht4vNDiGqZQNs/1))

```
CREATE TABLE testing (
   pageid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   position SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (pageid),
   UNIQUE idx_position (position)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Thanks, so it's a naming conflict. And what about using directly `UNIQUE (position)`, would that be allowed?

Comment: It's allowed, InnoDb would automatically create a unique name for the constraint

Comment: Yes, MySQL will name this index automatically

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.